# How can I do an in list option

Tags: xslt

In Pseudo code

```
If Domain inList(GB,US,ES,FR Then
   Print This Html
Else
  Print This HTML
EndIf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a*very* general form, but where you don't know the list at design-time, so long as you can get a reference to a nodeset which represents the list you can do a simple test like:

```
<xsl:when test="$listset/item[@property=$variable]">
```

where say $variable = /foo/bar/@property and $listset = /foo/list for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar property="gb" />
  <list>
    <item property="gb"/>
    <item property="us"/>
  </list>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [xsl:choose.](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/el_choose.asp) (Also see [the spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose)) It provides a basic if/else functionality. EDIT- I did test and it works:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="domain = 'GB' or domain = 'US' or domain = 'ES' or domain = 'FR'">
    print this html
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    print other html
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 given the file

You can use something like this:

`<xsl:template match="list/item">

Property [<xsl:value-of select="@property"/>] html

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="list/item[some $x in ('us', 'gb') satisfies $x eq @property ]">

Property [<xsl:value-of select="@property"/>]  HTML

</xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution, not mentioned by the current 3 answers** is to have a string of the options against which you are comparing the value of `domain`. Then the following XPath expression (in the `@test` attribute of either `<xsl:if>`  or `<xsl:when>` evaluates to `true()` exactly when the value of `domain` is one of the delimited values in the string (we use a space for delimiter in this concrete example):

**`contains(' GB US ES ', concat(' ', domain, ' '))`**

Here we suppose that there are no spaces in the value of `domain`. If this cannot be guaranteed, the XPath expression can also verify this requirement:

**`not(contains(domain, ' '))`** 
 **`and`**
  **`contains(' GB US ES ', concat(' ', domain, ' '))`**